# Sort array of filepaths by filename

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I use `directory.listFiles()` to get list of files recursively from a given directory structure.
I tried to use following codes for this purpose, but none of them are working.

```
    Arrays.sort(fList, Comparator.comparing(File::getName));
    Arrays.sort(fList, NameFileComparator.NAME_COMPARATOR);
```

Files should be listed in ascending order from all the subdirectories.

Comment: Could you please add some more code and information? How do your comparators look and what exactly is not working (*how* is it not working)?

Answer (score 5):

File is a comparable class, which by default sorts pathnames lexicographically. Just use ,

```
 Arrays.sort(fList);
```

If you want to sort them differently, you can define your own comparator.

Comment: I need to sort all the files from all the subfolders also by filename. If I use that code files aren't sorted only by its filenames from directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort all the file paths recursively in a tree structure, you can try `Files.walk` using `sorted` with a Java 8 stream:

```
List<String> files = Files.walk(Paths.get("/tmp"))
                         .filter(Files::isRegularFile) // Check you have only file names
                         .map(Path::toString) // map to string
                         .sorted() // sort
                         .collect(Collectors.toList()); // create list
```

If you want case insensitive sorting:

```
List<String> files = Files.walk(Paths.get("d:/tmp"))
                         .filter(Files::isRegularFile) // Check you have only file names
                         .map(Path::toString) // map to string
                         .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::toLowerCase)) // sort case insensitive
                         .collect(Collectors.toList()); // create list
```

Answer (score 1):

To list all files within directory and subdirectories use [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) `FilesUtil.listFiles` method

```
Collection<File> fCollection = FileUtils.listFiles(directory, null, true);
File[] fList = fCollection.toArray(new File[fCollection.size()]);
```

Then to sort the array you can just use

```
Arrays.sort(fList);
```